# Delete element from a list while changing scene in Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a list with 7 elements in Unity. At the beginning of the scene, one element is getting activated for 3 seconds and then deactivated. Then the user has to search for this element in the scene and once he/she finds it to press the trigger button to advance to the next scene. What I want to achieve is to remove the elements that have already been activated, so the user does not see them in the next scenes. So, if in the first scene the element 6 was activated, then in the second scene any element can be activated but not 6. And so on and so forth for the next scenes. Until now, I have the script below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrialHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TrialHandler instance;
    public List<GameObject> objectsList = new List<GameObject>();
    private int currentObject;
    private float timer;
    [HideInInspector] public static int trialNum = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        objectsList.RemoveAll(item => item = null);
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        currentObject = Random.Range(0, objectsList.Count);
        objectsList[currentObject].SetActive(true);
        trialNum += 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= 3.0f)
        {
            objectsList[currentObject].SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for the most part except that it repeats elements that the user has already seen as he/she goes over the scenes. I have put this code  `objectsList.RemoveAll(item => item = null);` but it doesn't seem to get rid off the elements that have been deactivated once a new scene is loaded.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Update: The problem seems to be that when the scene starts all the elements are being deactivated (with only one random element being activated). Because of this when the next scene loads the list does not become populated with the remaining elements. However, I cannot activate all the elements from the very beginning because I want only one to be displayed at each scene.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to remove the gameobject from the list when you go to the next scene.i.e. when you click(trigger button-onclick listener) the next scene.No need to remove the all the items.Since you are using DontDestroyOnLoad you could use RemoveAt(index).

```
int index = TrialHandler.instance.objectsList
TrialHandler.instance.objectsList.RemoveAt(currentObject) //Currentobject is the index.
```

Comment: Why I need to use TrialHandler.instance. ? Can't I use directly objectList.RemoveAt(currentObject)? The problem is that I use objectList.RemoveAt(currentObject) but it doesn't remove the item. It throws MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object. TrialHandler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TrialHandler.cs:32)

Comment: @Phoenix Yes you can use like that if you are writing the onClick() function for trigger button using the same script.That will rise to new issue because in the update you want the gameobject to hide that will cause an argument exception error.You are removing the object from the list and in update you  are trying to hide the same object.This is not possible as the object is already removed.In the scene after 3 seconds the gameobject will be hidden?

Comment: Let's assume we have object 6 in scene 1. The scene starts, object 6 is being activated for 3 seconds and then deactivated. The user does what he has to do and press the trigger button to advance to the next scene. At the beginning of scene 2, another object from the list (but definitely not object 6) has to be activated for 3 seconds and then deactivated. This happens until the list contains no objects. So, my list has 7 objects, this means that it will go up to scene 7, each time activating and deactivating a DIFFERENT object.

Comment: The problem I have is that I get the same object in more than one scenes. For example, object 6 in scene 1, object 6 in scene 2, object 5 in scene 3, object 1 in scene 4, etc. In this example I got object 6 more than once (in scene 1 and in scene 2), which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list contains `GameObjects` you can just compare like for like. In `TrialHandler` add a new void:

```
public void RemoveObject(Gameobject g)
{
   objectsList.Remove(g);
}
```

As you're using a singleton pattern you can access TrialHandler via a script on the clicked objects. Use the `IPointerClickHandler` interface to detect the click (or alternatively use [raycasting](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)):

```
public class ClickedObject: IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        TrialHandler.instance.RemoveObject(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think the problem is somewhere else. In the first scene, the list is getting populated as it should (7 elements with their names). When I load the next scene (second, third, etc.) it has again 7 elements but it shows Missing(Game Object) and it throws 2 errors:

Comment: 1. MissingReferenceException: The variable objectsList of TrialHandler doesn't exist anymore.
You probably need to reassign the objectsList variable of the 'TrialHandler' script in the inspector.
TrialHandler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TrialHandler.cs:32)
2. MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
TrialHandler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TrialHandler.cs:32)

Comment: I wonder if it's because you're instantiating with the declaration? I assume you're assigning items to the list in the inspector? If so try removing ` = new List<GameObject>()`

Comment: Yep, you are right. I assign items to the list in the inspector. I deleted the ' = new List <Gameobject>()' but it didn't change anything. Also, I see in the hierarchy that each time I load a new scene it creates several new instances under the Don't destroy on Load.

Comment: Is the GameObject holding TrialHandler a child of another object?

Comment: The TrialHandler script is attached to a TrialManager GameObject and when I press play the TrialManager appears below the DontDestroyonLoad.

Comment: Hmm, stumped. I'll try to recreate the issue when I get off work tonight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245228/discussion-between-phoenix-and-absinthe).